# Install another helm chart, for each value in a parent helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a helm chartX :-

values.yaml:
someList : a,b,c
templates:

- deployServiceA.yaml

Now, I want to install another helm chartY, for each entry in the someList.

example, if someList has a,b and c, I want to install a helm chart Y, in namespace fx-a, fx-b and fx-c

how can I achieve this using helm charts?

How can

Comment: Plain Helm can't do this, since a chart's dependencies are a flat list with the only option being the ability to selectively disable individual dependencies.  It's possible tools like [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) might be able to, though.

Comment: Each of them should have their own helm charts. If you want to trigger parents and not to run or run child charts, there is a condition option on dependency. If needed to separate all of them with some condition(s), you totally need Helmfile.